# Постепенно уменьшается свободное место на локальном диске C

Tags: windows

У меня где-то 3-4 дня назад начала увеличиваться память на локальном диске C. После включения или перезагрузки компьютера, она остается которая была (перед началом увеличения). Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Было 300ГБ, стало 600ГБ? Или может я недопонял чего?

Comment: Было 7 гб , а через 30 минут 6.76И так далее

Comment: Торрент-клиент запущен?

Comment: У меня нету торрентаЯ им не пользуюсь

Comment: @Дима123, а чем пользуетесь? Поподробнее, будьте так добры. А то получается типа "Доктор, у меня что-то где-то не так..."**ЗЫ**> ...начала увеличиваться память...Сформулируйте,пожалуйста, корректно.

Comment: Все что у меня лежит на диске С,так это :1.Фотошоп(пользуюсь каждый день)2.Варкрафт 3(нечего не качаю туда)3.КартинкиВсе...У меня начала увеличиваться память,после того как,выскачило"Замените пожалуйста батарею"Не знаю,влияет ли как  - то или нет.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию

Answer (score 5):

1. Зубы по телефону не лечат
2. Вангование сейчас модно, но не каждый может.. Я, например, не могу. Мы даже не знаем какая у Вас система. Семейство Win не так мало.
3. Память не увеличивается. Уменьшается количество свободного пространства.
4. Установите файл подкачки не "По выбору системы", а, например, 2048-2050.
5. Уберите уход в сон, удалите в корне диска C: фаил hiberfil.sys (так, кажется). Это не влияет на Вашу проблему, но наделит вас свободным пространством.
6. В меню "Переменные среды" настройте переменные %temp% и %tmp% не на диск C:\xxx а на D:\Temp (например).
7. Сделайте дефрагментацию диска C:\
8. Найдите в интернете, куда ваш браузер сохраняет временные файлы (cache), переназначте эту директорию на диск D:\

Подучите русский язык.

Почитайте: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html

Еще раз ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО почитайте: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html

С уверенностью в 80% говорю, что Ваша проблема в пунктах 6 и 8. Когда вы читаете новости в контакте, смотрите картинки, видео, все это подгружается на диск. В результате chrome через 3 минуты листания новостей вк жрет примерно 400 метров, и еще 300 складывает на диск. После перезагрузки временные файлы очищаются, что дает вам нужный эффект.

Так же, Вы можете посмотреть это программой Ccleaner. Автоматическая очистка в момент, когда у вас меньше места - удалит временные файлы.

Если что-то в моем ответе не понятно, не ленитесь воспользоваться ссылкой: http://google.ru и поискать то, что Вас заинтересовало.

Answer (score 0):

а) пишутся логи; б) качаются обновы - что Фотошоп, что вовка; толстеет каталог WinSxS; г) динамический файл подкачки.  Нужен монитор для ФС, либо запустить хотя бы секвойю и ручками глянуть - что там на диске вообще живет.